# how to increase performance of summing a column

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance, correlated-subquery

I am trying to tune my query but I can't go further. is there any chance to tune more this query? especially SUM sub query.

INDEX : db_prices.date

Example of original query:

```
SELECT
db_villas.id,
db_villas.title1,
db_specials.id AS sid,
db_specials.title1 AS stitle,
db_cities.name AS cityName,
db_counties.name AS countyName,
db_assets.path,
db_villas.bathroom,
db_villas.bedroom,
db_villas.guest,
db_prices.date,
(SELECT SUM(db_prices.price) FROM db_prices WHERE db_prices.date BETWEEN "2016-08-01" AND "2016-09-30" AND db_prices.villaId=db_villas.id) AS price
FROM
db_villas
INNER JOIN db_cities ON db_villas.cityId = db_cities.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN db_specials ON db_villas.specialId = db_specials.id
INNER JOIN db_counties ON db_counties.cityid = db_cities.id AND db_villas.countyId = db_counties.id
INNER JOIN db_assets ON db_assets.guid = db_villas.guid
INNER JOIN db_villafacilities ON db_villafacilities.villaId = db_villas.id
INNER JOIN db_prices ON db_prices.villaId = db_villas.id
WHERE db_prices.date BETWEEN "2016-08-01" AND "2016-09-30" AND db_assets.isMainImage=1 AND db_villas.minRent <= 7
GROUP BY db_villas.id
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_prices WHERE date BETWEEN "2016-08-01" AND "2016-09-30" AND db_prices.isFree = 0 AND db_prices.villaId = db_villas.id)=0
```

the query at above executed in 1.2 seconds.

When I remove

```
(SELECT SUM(db_prices.price) FROM db_prices WHERE db_prices.date BETWEEN "2016-08-01" AND "2016-09-30" AND db_prices.villaId=db_villas.id) AS price
```

sub query execution time reduced up to 0.009 seconds.

If I just remove this part

```
AND db_prices.villaId=db_villas.id
```

from the sub query it's still executed in 0.009 seconds.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see the execution plan of your queries. It tells you which parts do not use the right index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL (as of v 5.7) has a query planner without the chops to transform your dependent subquery

```
 (SELECT SUM(db_prices.price) 
    FROM db_prices
   WHERE db_prices.date BETWEEN "2016-08-01" AND "2016-09-30"
     AND db_prices.villaId=db_villas.id) AS price
```

into a joinable independent subquery.  That means the query planner ends up running that query many times, using up time. So you need to transform it yourself. The independent subquery will look like this:

```
                 SELECT villaId, 
                        SUM(price) price,  
                        SUM(CASE WHEN isFree = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) not_free_count
                   FROM db_prices
                  WHERE date BETWEEN  '2016-08-01' AND '2016-09-30'
                  GROUP BY villaId
```

This query gives you the sum of prices, and the count of villas not tagged isFree, for each villa.  This is handy, because you can now JOIN this to the rest of your table. Like so:

```
 SELECT db_villas.id,
        db_villas.title1, etc etc,
        price_summary.price
   FROM db_villas
  INNER JOIN db_cities ON db_villas.cityId = db_cities.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN db_specials ON db_villas.specialId = db_specials.id
           etc etc.
   LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT villaId, 
                        SUM(price) price,  
                        SUM(CASE WHEN isFree = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) not_free_count
                   FROM db_prices
                  WHERE date BETWEEN  '2016-08-01' AND '2016-09-30'
                  GROUP BY villaId
       ) price_summary ON db_villas.villaId = price_summmary.villaId
 WHERE db_prices.date BETWEEN "2016-08-01" AND "2016-09-30"
   AND etc etc
   AND price_summary.not_free_count = 0
 GROUP BY db_villas.villaId
```

Then, you need the compound index on db_prices `(date, villaId, price, isFree)` to optimize your subquery.  You may also need indexes on some other columns of other tables.

**Pro tip:** Lots of single-column indexes are no substitute for compound indexes in speeding up queries. Indexing lots of columns individually is a common, and notorious, antipattern. Read this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

**Pro tip:** Your query is using the non-standard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. In a version of MySQL you may have soon, this will stop working unless you change some server settings. Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 2):

To speed this subquery:

```
(SELECT SUM(p.price)
 FROM db_prices p
 WHERE p.date BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2016-09-30' AND 
       p.villaId = db_villas.id
) AS price
```

You want an index.  The best index is a covering index with these columns in this order:  `db_prices(villaId, date, price)`.  A covering index includes all the columns in the subquery.

The column `villaId` should be first because it has an equality condition; then `date` because it is also in the `where` clause.  Finally, `price` is in the index just to make the processing a little more efficient -- all the columns are in the index so the engine does not need to look up values in the data pages.

Comment: date already indexed but I change indexes and orders as you wrote here. But query still executed in 1.1 seconds is it normal? can't we go further more?

Comment: take out that embedded select from your main select statement, add this as a join otherwise it's going to get called for every row of your result set rather than just the once as if it were in a join

Comment: @EricLaboy . . . How does the performance of this version compare to Ollie's version?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the aggregate first and join it with the table

```
SELECT
db_villas.id,
db_villas.title1,
db_specials.id AS sid,
db_specials.title1 AS stitle,
db_cities.name AS cityName,
db_counties.name AS countyName,
db_assets.path,
db_villas.bathroom,
db_villas.bedroom,
db_villas.guest,
db_prices.date,
pricesum
FROM (SELECT db_prices.villaId, SUM(db_prices.price) as pricesum FROM db_prices WHERE db_prices.date BETWEEN "2016-08-01" AND "2016-09-30"  group by db_prices.villaId) as prices
INNER JOIN  db_villas ON prices.villaId = db_villas.id
...
```

Sometimes this helps.

**EDIT**
corrected some copy errors

Comment: with this trick execution time reduced to 0.25 seconds :) Thank you

Comment: didn't look close enough at the subquery in the having-clause, not so Oliie Jones

Answer (score 0):

Create a multicolumn(composite) index this would solve your problem

To do this hit the below query

```
create index <some_name> on db_prices(date,villaId);
```

If you face further problems post your explain statement for further investigation